# Configuring php7.0 with apache2

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php-fpm, php-cli, php7

I'm running the newly released php7.0 on debian jessie. By now it works all fine.

Enabling the pdo_mysqli, I have found mutliple configuration directories for php7. There are:

```
apache2
cli
fpm
```

I'm aware, that the cli is the command-line php configuration. I also know that I had to enable the mysql in the php.ini of the fpm directory.

My question is: Why is there an apache2 configuration directory? Could I use php7 without fpm?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Each of these subdirectories holds configuration for a different PHP SAPI module, respectively: Apache2 module, command line, FPM. You haven't mentioned *cgi/* subdirectory, which is for CGI and FastCGI (other than run by FPM, ie. started by Apache process manager).

And of course, you don't need *fpm/* subdirectory if you don't use FPM SAPI. Simply uninstall the corresponding Debian package (*php7-fpm* I guess).